# How to make a removable audio element in contenteditable div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `contenteditable` property. I can insert any text or image and then remove it or navigate around it. How can I have a paragraph with `audio` element that will work the same?

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
  Hello
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-TG100-Whistle-C5.wav"/>
    </audio>
  </p>
</div>
```

In the example, you cannot move the cursor behind the last `p` element, you can't also remove it with any key.

Comment: That's true it's impossible to move the cursor after the last p element, but I'm able to cancel it after I deleted all the other elements.

Comment: I'm able too to delete the audio element, but when the target is clear

Comment: This way it's possible indeed, but it's not really satisfactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is similar to Marcos Pérez Gude's answer but space should be within `p` element and there should be one on the front if the `audio` element is first in the div.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
  Hello
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    &nbsp;
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-TG100-Whistle-C5.wav"/>
    </audio>
    &nbsp;
  </p>
  
</div>
```

The only caveat is that it will brake if you will delete the space while editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a space after `</p>` user can put the caret after the audio element

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
  Hello
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-TG100-Whistle-C5.wav"/>
    </audio>
  </p>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Then e.g. I cannot add any text in the same line (I want the same flexibility as with images etc.)

Comment: So I can suggest you to make this with a WYSIWYG editor, and not with `contenteditable` attribute. A very well wysiwyg is http://ckeditor.com/ . You can put it inline, without controls, and the result will be the same. You cannot made in contenteditable the same in images and in audio component, because audio component have got events to control the audio itself, but images not